# Keyboard in UISheetPresentationController push view up

Tags: ios, swift, uikeyboard, presentviewcontroller

I have view controller that I push via sheetPresentationController:

```
    let addRSSSheetVC = AddRSSSheetViewController()
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: addRSSSheetVC)
    
    if let sheet = navigationController.sheetPresentationController {
        sheet.detents = [.medium()]
    }
    
    present(navigationController, animated: true)
```

And when sheet present is look like this:

[image]

But when I click on textfield and keyboard present it push sheet view up:

[image]

How can I present keyboard above presented view controller without pushing page ?